# HTTPWebRequest Login POST is not Redirecting

Tags: vb.net, post, httpwebrequest

I need to use HTTPWebRequest to login to an external website and redirect me to the default page. My code below is behind a button - when clicked it currently tries to do some processing but stays on the same page. I need it to redirect me to the default page of the external website without seeing the login page. Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

```
    Dim loginURL As String = "https://www.example.com/login.aspx"

    Dim cookies As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer
    Dim myRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(loginURL), HttpWebRequest)
    myRequest.CookieContainer = cookies
    myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1"

    Dim myResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Dim responseReader As StreamReader
    responseReader = New StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim responseData As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
    responseReader.Close()

    'call a function to extract the viewstate needed to login
    Dim ViewState As String = ExtractViewState(responseData)

    Dim postData As String = String.Format("__VIEWSTATE={0}&txtUsername={1}&txtPassword={2}&btnLogin.x=27&btnLogin.y=9", ViewState, "username", "password")
    Dim encoding As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim data As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

    'POST to login page
    Dim postRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(loginURL), HttpWebRequest)
    postRequest.Method = "POST"
    postRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    postRequest.ContentLength = data.Length
    postRequest.CookieContainer = cookies
    postRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1"

    Dim newStream = postRequest.GetRequestStream()
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    newStream.Close()

    Dim postResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(postRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

   'using GET request on default page
    Dim getRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com/default.aspx"), HttpWebRequest)
    getRequest.CookieContainer = cookies
    getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True

    Dim getResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(getRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    'returns statuscode = 200
```

FYI - when i add in this code at the end, i get the HTML of the default page I'm trying to redirect to

```
Dim responseReader1 As StreamReader
responseReader1 = New StreamReader(getRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())

responseData = responseReader1.ReadToEnd()
responseReader1.Close()
Response.Write(responseData)
```

Any help on whats missing to get the redirect working?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The HttpWebRequest only automatically redirects you if the server sends an HTTP 3xx redirection status with a Location field in the response. Otherwise you are supposed to manually navigate to the page by using Response.Redirect, for example. Also keep in mind that the automatic redirection IGNORES ANY COOKIES sent by the server. That may be the problem in your case if the server is actually sending a redirection status.